# How to set Gruntfile to ignore files with underscore?

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

I have several files in my LESS folder with a underscore before the file name. Example:

```
_variables.less
_colors.less
```

These files only store data used on other `.less` files, so they should not have the `.css` file generated.

Is there any way to set a "ignore" on my `gruntfile.js` for this kind of file?

Here is my current setup:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            options: {
            manage: false
        },

        my_target: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/js',
                src: '*.js',
                dest: 'assets/js/min' 
            }]
        },
    },
    less: {
        components: {
            options: {
                imports: {
                    reference: [
                        "assets/less/**/*.less",  
                    ]
                }   
            },

            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/less',
                src: [
                    'input.less'
                ],
                dest: 'assets/css/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        styles: {
            files: ['assets/less/**/*.less', 'assets/js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['less', 'newer:uglify'],
            options: {
                nospawn: truetasks
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch', 'newer:uglify']);
};
```

Comment: There is only one less file in your `src` array, so I do not see how you can be generating any CSS files other than input.css.

Comment: You could try to exclude like '!_*.less' perhaps?